# Cypress V11 failing to start in Jenkins

Tags: reactjs, cypress, gui-testing

```
[STARTED] Task without title.
[FAILED] Cypress failed to start.
[FAILED] 
[FAILED] This may be due to a missing library or dependency. https://on.cypress.io/required-dependencies
[FAILED] 
[FAILED] Please refer to the error below for more details.
[FAILED] 
[FAILED] ----------
[FAILED] 
[FAILED] Command was killed with SIGSEGV (Segmentation fault): /root/.cache/Cypress/11.2.0/Cypress/Cypress --no-sandbox --smoke-test --ping=265
[FAILED] 
[FAILED] ----------
[FAILED] 
[FAILED] Platform: linux-arm64 (Debian - 11.4)
[FAILED] Cypress Version: 11.2.0
Cypress failed to start.
```

Versions: Cypress: 11.2.0
Node: 18.9.0
Debian: 11.4 (arm64)
React: 17.0.2

This is working locally in docker but fails in my Jenkins pipeline. Both are running identical commands.

Comment: Hi Ria, There is still an open issue for this here: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/7048.
a suggestion by travis-ci is to delete the cache : https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/common-build-problems/#segmentation-faults-from-the-language-interpreter-ruby-python-php-nodejs-etc

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.